# Importing all files in a directory as modules, and calling a class method

Tags: python

I have a module that includes signal processors in a subdirectory.  I'd like to have things set up so that the main file (above that subdirectory) can import all python files in the subdirectory, and call a known function in them.  This is so that the input signal can be run through each signal processor in that directory.  Is there a clean way to do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the files tree is:

```
main.py
processors/
processors/proc1.py
processors/proc1.py
```

and each *proc* module has a method:

```
def process():
    # Do something
```

Then you can use the following code from *main.py*:

```
import pkgutil
import processors

if __name__ == '__main__':
    modules = []
    for loader, name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(processors.__path__):
        modules.append(loader.find_module(name).load_module(name))

    # Later in the code when processing is required:
    for module in modules:
        module.process()
```

This code lacks input checks, e.g. each module has *process()* method.